# Проверка введённых пользователем данных

Tags: mysql, php, изображения, безопасность, форма

Всем доброго времени суток, разрабатывая свой первый сайт столкнулся с проблемой которая вроде бы уже обсуждалась сотни раз - обработка данных. Перечитал кучу статей и форумов, но так и не пришёл к чему-то однозначному. Авторы так же расходились во мнениях или не слишком хорошо раскрывали эту тему. И так, несколько вопросов. Так как я только учусь, прошу делать замечания по всему (оформление кода и т.д.).

**test.php**

```
session_start();
include("db.php");

function get_error($error) {
    header("location:index.php?error=".$error);
    exit;
}

//Этих проверок достаточно?
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) // - заносится из БД после аутентификации
    AND isset($_POST['text']) // - текстовая строка
    AND isset($_POST['number']) // - число
    AND isset($_POST['array_1']) // - массив 1
    AND isset($_POST['array_2']) // - массив 2
    AND isset($_FILES['photo_1']) // - изображение которое обязательно должно быть загружено
    AND isset($_FILES['photo_2']) // - изображение которое не обязательно для загрузки
    AND !empty($_SESSION['id'])
    AND !empty($_POST['text'])
    AND !empty($_POST['number'])
    AND !empty($_POST['array_1'])
    AND !empty($_POST['array_2'])
    AND !empty($_FILES['photo_1'])) {

    //Лучше сразу всё из пост в переменные вывести? ($text = $_POST['text']; и т.д.)
    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ %().,!?:\"\r\n-]{3,100}$/u", $_POST['text'])) {

        $text = trim($_POST['text']);
        $text = stripslashes($_POST['text']); //на всякий случай, если magic_quotes включен
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']); // - некоторые писали что это не панацея

        //допустим эта запись должна быть уникальной
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `text` FROM `myTable` WHERE `text`='$text' LIMIT 1", $db);

        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) {
                get_error(10);
            }
        } else {
          get_error(9);
        }

    } else {
        get_error(8);
    }

    //Правильно ли так проверять числа?
    if((int)$_POST['number'] < 5 || (int)$_POST['number'] > 15) { 
        get_error(7); 
    }

    //нужно ли сравнивать их количество, если они должны быть одинакового размера?
    if(count($_POST['array_1']) != count($_POST['array_2'])) {
        get_error(6);
    }

    //Всё учтено?
    if($_FILES['photo_1']['error'] == 0 OR $_FILES['photo_1']['size'] > 2097152) {
        $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['photo_1']['tmp_name']);

        if($imageinfo['mime'] == 'image/png' 
            OR $imageinfo['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'
            OR $imageinfo['mime'] == 'image/pjpeg') {

            //опустим переименование файла
            // допустим каталог нужно создать по схем "res/user/2013/11/20" то при каждой записи проверять is_dir()? или mkdir() без проблем создаст если нету?
            $upload_dir = 'res/user/';
            $upload_file = $upload_dir.basename($_FILES['photo_1']['name']);

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_1']['tmp_name'], $upload_file)) {
                get_error(5);
            }
        } else {
            get_error(4);
        }

    } else {
        get_error(3);
    }

    if(!empty($_FILES['photo_2'])) {
        // те же махинации что и с $_FILES['photo_1']
    } else {
        $upload_file_2 = "0"; // или NULL ?
    }

    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];

    $result = mysql_query ("
              INSERT INTO `myTable` (`text`, `number`, `photo_1`, `photo_2`)
              VALUES('$text','$result','$upload_file','$upload_file_2')";
    if(!$result) {
        get_error(2);
    }

    header("location:index.php"); //hello world!
    exit;

} else {
    get_error(1);
}
```

Думал за день сделаю это.Начал читать и вникать, аж вскипел, без пива тут не обошлось.
Кто то советует и htmlspecialchars(), и strip_tags(), и ещё чего то там, кто во что горазд...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [[@Billy Milligan](/users/15506/billy-milligan)](/users/15506/billy-milligan), обратите внимание на комментарий [[@NoName](/users/12132/noname)](/users/12132/noname)! Правда, он не раскрыл суть, но по ссылке, в принципе, всё коротко и ясно описано. Использовать метод **mysql_*** для работы с БД - это устаревший метод. Раз вы в начале своего обучения, то тем более **надо** сразу пользоваться современными функциями. PDO или MySQLi - избавять вас от многих проблем. Кроме этого, вам уже не понадобяться функции "mysql_real_escape_string()" и т.д.
2. Обрабатывать глобальные переменные можно следующим образом:

   ```
   if(!empty($_POST['val1'])) $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
   if(!empty($_POST['val2'])) $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
   if(!empty($_POST['val3'])) $val3 = $_POST['val3'];
   // теперь достаточно перечислить все необходимые для существования переменные через запятую:
   if(isset($val1,$val2,$val3)) {
       // всё гуд, можно продолжать
   }
   ```
3. Не вижу смысла в следующей строке:

   ```
   if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ %().,!?:\"\r\n-]{3,100}$/u", $_POST['text']))
   ```
4. :

   ```
   //Правильно ли так проверять числа?
   if((int)$_POST['number'] < 5 || (int)$_POST['number'] > 15)
   ```

   Почему бы и нет. Только надо учитывать, что *(int)'abc123';* будет выдавать "0"
5. "*проверять is_dir()? или mkdir()*" - проверять, т.к. если директория существует, то выдаст ошибку
6. "*$upload_file_2 = "0"; // или NULL ?*" - Если для поля вы задавали значение NOT NULL или какое-то свое значение по умолчанию, то NULL в таком случае вызовет ошибку. Просто будьте внимательны в таких случаях

P.S. Фильтрацию переменных, как предлагали выше, к примеру я, использую абсолютно во всех проектах, где это требуется. Может быть не часто filter_input_array(), но уж filter_var()  - так уж точно. Скажем, если надо проверить валиден ли email или надо очистить текст от URL и т.д. - функция просто замечтательная.

Comment: Поддержу про PDO, удобно и просто)

Comment: Спасибо, обратил внимание, и уже успел кое-что прочитать про mysqli)

`if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ %().,!?:\"\r\n-]{3,100}$/u", $_POST['text']))`

А как же мне сообщить пользователю что он вводит не то что надо?

Comment: Хотя я сейчас задался вопросом нужно ли оно мне и зачем люди вообще ставят ограничение на ввод символов...

Comment: @Billy Milligan, вот вот... Ведь по сути, главная задача - это обезопасить добавляемые данные в БД (*касамо тех же постов, комментов и иже с ними*). Отдельным пунктом идет проверка на правильность вводимых данных (напр., тот же email, телефон, номер кредитки и т.д.), но это уже совсем другая история. Некоторые еще безуспешно пытаются бороться с матом в постах теми же регулярками - а это уже граничит с паранойей ;) В общем, в первую очередь,  страхуемся (*слово, которое не прошло бы мат-контроль )) *) от инъекций.

Comment: ну ограничение на ввод количесва символов имеет смысл иногда... например тут в комменты можно ввести определенное количество символов, так же как и есть минимальное количество для коммента ;)

Answer (score 2):

А я вот это тут оставлю: [Data Filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) :)
В частности [`filter_input_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

Comment: Воу воу воу, сильно ;) 

вот это уже лучше)

Вы в своих проектах используете данный способ? И на сколько быстро он отрабатывает, я думаю явно быстрее чем то что я нагарадил?)

Comment: Вообше не замерял разницу в скорости, если я правильно помню, то filter это обертка над regexp'ами посути :)

а так, да, использую, хотя некоторые личности на phpclub.ru говорят, что ненадо это использовать, даже приводили примеры где оно не с работает.

вот так например я использую:

    $def_lang = 'ru';
    $cur_lang = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "lang", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($cur_lang == NULL || $cur_lang === false || !in_array($cur_lang, $_avail_langs) ) { $cur_lang = $def_lang; }

Comment: Кстати достаточно древние функции, но за вю жищнь не встречал их использования :) Может просто не те исходники смотрел :))

Answer (score 0):

Просто оставлю это здесь:

- `is_numeric()`
- `trim()`
- `mysql_real_escape_string()`
- `is_array()`

ну и [Многобайтные строки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php)

Вообще я бы на твоем месте вынес проверку в отдельную функцию и не делал все в одном условии. Просто:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
if (!is_numeric($_POST[''])) {
$error[]='';
}


if (isset($error)) {
//~ существуют ошибки
}
```

Comment: Вы серьёзно?

Почему то я не увидел ответа ни на один вопрос...
Такое ощущение что вы даже не читали, а просто оставлять здесь ничего не надо.

is_numeric() съест и "-2.34768e10+76", и "0xFF".